# Django admin site foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-django-storages

I have created some classes like STATE, DISTRICT, TALUK, and VILLAGE. Admin needs to add details in the admin panel.
If the admin needs to add TALUK, he must select provided STATE, DISTRICT.I used a foreign key in the TALUK class for calling states and districts. But in admin after selecting STATE, the DISTRICT dropdown shows all the DISTRICTS. I need to get only the districts of that particular state

This is the code I wrote in models.py

```
class STATE(models.Model):

    state_name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name
    
class DISTRICT(models.Model):
    
    district_state=models.ForeignKey(STATE,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district_name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.district_name

class TALUK(models.Model):
    
    taluk_state=models.ForeignKey(STATE,default=1,verbose_name="state",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taluk_district=models.ForeignKey(DISTRICT,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taluk_name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.taluk_name

class VILLAGE(models.Model):
    
    taluk_vill=models.ForeignKey(TALUK,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vill_name=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vill_name
```

Comment: Why providing STATE name is mandatory when adding a new TALUK? I mean, the DISTRICT field implicitly contains the STATE information. "taluk_state" field seems reduntant

Comment: in taluk if you select state,then it needs to show only districts of that state.else it shows all the districts of all states